# php different output of echo and var_dump

Tags: php

Why does `echo("$objInst->property | $objInst->propertyTwo");` return a different value to `echo($objInst->property."|".$objInst->propertyTwo);` ?

Here's the output of an echo with everything wrapped in ""s, incorrect values

```
oun}wuuw}olo~seou}n~yoyvu zewus in@@@0~and drop it@@@0
```

Here's the output of an echo with only the pipe in ""s, correct values.

```
chk|0|Who has actually read infinite jest|~not me@@@0~i get about 80-120 pages in@@@0~and drop it@@@0|Free Trade|Manufacturing Consent
```

Have you guys run into anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`echo("{$objInst->property} | {$objInst->propertyTwo}");`

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php